# Automatically get logged out as I try to login

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

I just started having this problem on 17.04. As I try to login on Ubuntu the screen just goes black for a second, and then I end up back on the login screen. I have tried reinstalling lightdm, that didn't work. I tried using gdm, that didn't work. I tried the following command `sudo rm -v .Xauthority`, didn't work.

The only thing that made it possible to log in was by creating a new user, but then I can't access my files. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean it started happening with no provocation? Did you install any updates/new packages or do any configuration?

Comment: @Zanna I don't think I installed any new packages or updates.

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `ls -al /home/your_username/.*thority` and I'll take a look. Please copy/paste that output into your question, not the comments please. Ping me with `@heynnema` when you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of you .Xauthority file in you home dir?

Try:

```
sudo chown username /home/username/.Xauthority
```

Replace username with your username, e.g. if your user name is `alex`:

```
sudo chown alex /home/alex/.Xauthority
```

And also make sire the permissions are set correctly:

```
sudo chmod 600 /home/username/.Xauthority
```

Comment: It didn't work, I still have the same problem